# How to call WiziQ API from iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, wiziq

I want to integrated [WiziQ](http://www.wiziq.com/) api with my iOS app. I have created account on it but i do't getting how to call that api using "Access Key" and " Secret Key". I have lots of googling but not getting any idea to how to create [User authentication](http://developer.wiziq.com/authentication) and call list of api.If any one have idea let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share that WizIQ API is not open source. You cannot integrate it with your iOS App by yourself. However, you can get it done through WizIQ itself as they provide whitelabelling services for the app.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply scratch the surface of the WizIQ developer site, it reveals the following about receiving the keys you speak of, specifically on the [Get API Keys](http://developer.wiziq.com/keys) page:

> **To obtain an API key**, you need to upgrade your account. Contact our sales team [here](http://developer.wiziq.com/contact-us) or **call
>   us at +1-919-647-4727**.